# Permission problem while downloading pdf from Flutter

Tags: flutter, http, dart, visual-studio-code

Given permission and created directory:

```
  void requestPersmission() async 
  {
    await PermissionHandler().requestPermissions([PermissionGroup.storage]);
  }

  void getHttp() async 
  {
    print("Got called");
    requestPersmission();

    Directory appDocDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    print(appDocDirectory);

    Directory directory =
        await new Directory(appDocDirectory.path + '/' + 'sulaksh')
            .create(recursive: true);
    print(directory);

    requestPersmission();


    var response =
        await Dio().download('https://www.google.com/', '$directory/xx.html');
  
    print(response);
  }
```

**AndriodManifest.xml**:
Here I have put the required permission:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.buttons">

     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />     
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />   />

    <application .......
```

Restarted the application many times, still getting this error:

```
E/flutter ( 4223): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception:  
FileSystemException: Creation failed, path = 'Directory: '' (OS Error: Read-only file  
system, errno = 30)
```

Comment: you should add read and write storage permission at menifest

Comment: Please how how to do that in your answer. @JahidulIslam

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> attach this line in menifest

Comment: @JahidulIslam I added both those lines and I am still getting the same error. I have updated the question

Comment: After adding the `read` and `write` permission, delete the app and reinstall.

Comment: I didn't understand. What to delete and reinstall? Flutter is the only thing that I have installed. I running this code through Visual Code Studio's emulator. @LucasJosino

Comment: Which is your Android version?